# How to get the user role in rest interface?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Actually I am getting all the users list in JSON response but not getting the user role in that listing.

What I have to do for user role?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are authenticated you should just have to add **?context=edit** to the request.

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/users?context=edit
```

Edit: This may only work if you query each user separately though as I believe you can only filter the user list by role, not list all the roles.

Comment: I am still getting this error: {"code":"rest_forbidden_context","message":"Sorry, you cannot view this resource with edit context.","data":{"status":401}}

Comment: right now i am getting the users in this way: http://yossiliron.webfactional.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users

Comment: how to query each user seperately?

Comment: I think you need to pass an Authentication token with your request

To get each user you would need to put in a request per user like this:
http://yossiliron.webfactional.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/92

Comment: This should be in the official documentation.